# Getting error while upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

I'm getting error messages while upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 using [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish) method after issuing "sudo apt update":

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190805) bionic InRelease
Ign:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1) jammy InRelease
Hit:3 cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190805) bionic Release
Err:4 cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1) jammy Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                 
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:8 http://c.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                             
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 http://c.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease          
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/gimp/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                        
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1) jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

My current OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

What's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: try `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`